# Indexeddb javascript - Inserting more value in existing value

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, indexeddb

What is the simplest way to insert new value data in existing value, for example, lets say that i have already stored data numbers : "one", and i want to insert the word "two" at the end for numbers : "one,two".

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is known as an *update*, not an insert. To update a value, read the value from indexedDB, edit the value, then save the updated value in place of the original value. You can use a put request for this purpose.

Comment: Am doing that, when the amount of string data is storing in db, everything is ok, but when the data getting larger, then it is not storing everything.

when is small data its normal : 
https://im.ge/i/FCh2Gm

when getting larger : 
https://im.ge/i/FCh1bf